# Replace empty values in a column with 'UNKNOWN'

Tags: awk

I have a tab-delimited file with 3 columns in which I want to replace the empty values in column two with the string "UNKNOWN". Here is part of the file:

```
MSTRG.1         0  
MSTRG.10        LOC102399924    331  
MSTRG.100       GINS4   108   
MSTRG.1000 UNKNOWN 0  
MSTRG.10000 UNKNOWN 0  
MSTRG.10001     BTBD19  86  
MSTRG.10002     TCTEX1D4        8  
MSTRG.10003     PLK3    627  
MSTRG.10004     LOC112585853    21996  
MSTRG.10005     LOC112585855    22  
MSTRG.10006     LOC112585856    1  
MSTRG.10007     LOC112585857    29  
MSTRG.10008     KIF2C   151  
MSTRG.10009     ARMH1   14  
MSTRG.1001 UNKNOWN 0  
MSTRG.10010 UNKNOWN 0  
MSTRG.10011     TMEM53  43  
MSTRG.10012     RNF220  4315  
MSTRG.10013     LOC112585696    100  
MSTRG.10014             234  
MSTRG.10015             918  
MSTRG.10016     DPH2    242  
MSTRG.10017     LOC112577732    705
```

I tried `awk -F'\t' '$2 && !$3{ $2="UNKNOWN" }1' file` but it did not replace the empty spaces in a few rows.

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, here is part of the same file using commas instead of tabs for better readability. I have converted the tab-delimited file into CSV  with `sed 's/\t/,/'g`.

```
MSTRG.1,,0
MSTRG.10,LOC102399924,331
MSTRG.100,GINS4,108
MSTRG.1000,LOC112585730,0
MSTRG.10000,LOC112585902,0
MSTRG.10013,LOC112585696,100
MSTRG.10014,,234
MSTRG.10015,,918
MSTRG.10016,DPH2,242
```

Comment: Since the site's formatting replaces tabs with spaces, it's hard to tell the structure of your data. Please consider posting an example with an alternate delimiter (such as `,` or `|`) that will be easier to work with.

Comment: Pl. check the updated question.

Comment: I would suggest `awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $2 == "" {$2 = "UNKNOWN"} 1' file`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158489/replace-empty-values-in-a-column-with-unknown#comment1928871_1158489), which should work fine, you could also just replace consecutive tabs (`\t\t`) with "UNKNOWN" surrounded by tabs  (`\tUNKNOWN\t`).

- With `sed`:

  ```
  sed -i 's/\t\t/\tUNKNOWN\t/' file
  ```

  - `-i` modifies the file in place.
- With `awk` version > 4.1.0:

  ```
  awk -i inplace '{sub(/\t\t/, "\tUNKNOWN\t")}1' file
  ```

  - `-i inplace` modifies the file in place.
  - `1` in the end just prints the file contents.
- With `awk` version < 4.1.0, the `-i inplace` option does not exist, so, to imitate `-i inplace`, you have to save the file to a temporary one and then rename it as your current one:

  ```
  awk '{sub(/\t\t/, "\tUNKNOWN\t")}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
  ```